# Dates aren't saving to Core Data Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate

I am converting NSDate from NSSting, and then I am adding this dates to Core Data object in this way

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{

    managedObjectContext = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].managedObjectContext;

    NSUInteger selectedString = [subjectPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];

    Subjects *selectedSubject = [subjectForEventArray objectAtIndex:selectedString];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Kyiv"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];

    NSLog(@" %@ %@ ", self.startDateForSubject, self.endDateForSubject);
    NSDate *sDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.startDateForSubject];
    NSDate *eDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.endDateForSubject];


    NSLog(@"%@ %@", eDate, sDate);


    selectedSubject.timeOfSubject.startDate = sDate;
    selectedSubject.timeOfSubject.endDate = eDate;
    selectedSubject.weekDay.dayOfWeek = _dayString;





    NSError *error;

    if ([managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        if (self.delegate) {
            [self.delegate selectedTeacherToControllerForIndexPath:self.scheduleCellIndexPath];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"delegate is not set and can not execute code");
        }
          NSLog(@"=== %@ === %@ === %@ ===",selectedSubject.timeOfSubject.startDate, selectedSubject.timeOfSubject.endDate, selectedSubject.weekDay.dayOfWeek);
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }


}
```

This is Log Window

```
2014-12-02 18:35:00.115 StudentSchedule[1003:38141]  04:50 06:45 
2014-12-02 18:35:00.117 StudentSchedule[1003:38141] 2000-01-01 04:45:00 +0000 2000-01-01 02:50:00 +0000
2014-12-02 18:35:00.118 StudentSchedule[1003:38141] === (null) === (null) === Monday, 11.12 ===
```

NSManagedObject subclass Subjects has relation timeOfSubject with another table "TimeOfSchedule", and there i have properties NSDate.

```
@class ReadySubject, Teacher, TimeOfSchedule;

@interface Subjects : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * article;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Teacher *teacherOfSubject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TimeOfSchedule *timeOfSubject;
```

and

```
@class Subjects;

@interface TimeOfSchedule : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * endDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * startDate;
```

The problem is, that this dates aren't saved in my Core Data, there are nulls, and I don't understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `timeOfSubject` is nil. Make sure your managed object is correctly set up and populated.

If you set a property of `timeOfSubject` it will not automatically insert a new `TimeOfSchedule` object as a relationship. You have to create it with `insertNewObject...`. and attach it to the `Subjects` entity.

*BTW: you should not pluralize your entity names, as this is not logical and quite confusing.

Use `Subject` instead.*

As for "correctly set up", did you create a reverse relationship from `TimeOfSchedule` back to `Subject`? At least you left it out in the code.

Comment: How I can check it? I am adding a schedule in another controller, then I am trying to set this time for a subject here. So at first this time is not attached with Subjects entity, I am trying to attach it here.

Comment: If the `TimeOfSchedule` object already exists, pass it to this controller or method. If not, create it. You add relationship with `schedule.subject = subject;`

Comment: Understood. I tried to pass an attributes of this table, instead of passing this object. Thank you.